# AngularJS - html rendering and ng-bind-html-unsafe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I have a bit problem with angularJS html rendering. The problem is when I use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` , the layout looks completely wrong. But then, I just hover the mouse around that area, everything just moves to its correct place. So somehow, I guess it has something related to angularJS custom attribute because things are completely fine without `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

```
<li><a href="#!/static/faq"
    ng-bind-html-unsafe="locale['static-faq']"></a></li>
<li><a href="#!/static/privacy-policy"
    ng-bind-html-unsafe="locale['static-privacy-policy']"></a></li>
<li><a href="#!/static/terms"
    ng-bind-html-unsafe="locale['static-terms']"></a></li>
<li><a href="#!/static/contact"
    ng-bind-html-unsafe="locale['static-contact']"></a></li>
<li><a href="#!/static/team"
    ng-bind-html-unsafe="locale['static-team']"></a></li>
```

Comment: What does your locale object look like? Set up a working example on jsfiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to not to be problem from angularJS. It's because of `text-decoration: uppercase` which I didn't expect it to be a problem.